# PHP XDebug autostart from single ip

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I'm using PHPStorm + remote XDebug (apache).
What is the easiest way to initiate debug back-connect for almost all http requests from my ip? BTW not all requests are made by browser.

Comment: Ooops. I think it's question for stackoverflow and I posted it here by mistake

Comment: See 'xdebug.remote_autostart' Xdebug configuration option (http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_autostart)

Comment: OK. But how to limit it's behaviour to single client's ip? somehow with php_admin_value etc.?

Comment: Are you going to use it on production?

Comment: This server is used in production also.